# Arithmetic mean is smaller or equal than geometric mean to the power of two

Tags: inequality

We consider $\displaystyle{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and $\displaystyle{a_{1}, a_{2}, . . . , a_{n} \in \big( 1, n \big]}$ then prove or disprove that
$$ \frac{a_{1} + a_{2} + \cdots + a_{n}}{n} \leqslant \Big( \sqrt[n]{a_{1} \cdot a_{2} \cdot . . . \cdot a_{n}} \Big)^{2} $$

Let $f \big( a_{1}, a_{2}, . . . , a_{n} \big) = \frac{a_{1} + a_{2} + \cdots + a_{n}}{n} - \Big( \sqrt[n]{a_{1} \cdot a_{2} \cdot . . . \cdot a_{n}} \Big)^{2} \leqslant 0 , \forall a_{1}, a_{2}, . . . , a_{n} \in \big( 1, n \big]$ which is a continous function and we find that $ b_{n} = f \big( 1, 1, . . . , n \big) = \frac{2 \cdot n-1+}{n} - \big( \sqrt[n]{n} \big)^{2}$
so the limit $ \lim\limits_{n \to + \infty} b_{n} = \lim\limits_{n \to + \infty} f \big( 1, 1, . . . , n \big) = 1 \Leftrightarrow \forall \epsilon > 0 : \exists n_{0} \in \mathbb{N} : \big| b_{n} - 1 \big| < \epsilon , \forall n \geqslant n_{0} $, so for $ \epsilon = \frac{1}{2} > 0 : \exists n_{0} \in  \mathbb{N} : \frac{1}{2} < b_{n} < \frac{3}{2} , \forall n \geqslant n_{0} $, so then for $ n \geqslant n_{0} $ : $ \frac{1}{2} < b_{n} = f \big( 1, 1, . . . , n \big) = \lim\limits_{\big( a_{1}, a_{2}, . . . , a_{n} \big) \to \big( 1^{+}, 1^{+}, . . . ,n \big)} f \big( a_{1}, a_{2} , . . . , a_{n} \big) \leqslant 0 $, is contradict.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I have an idea, about convex function, but I can not prove the inequality.

Comment: Are you sure? The RHS is pretty small when the $a_i$ are at extreme ends, so it' s quite easy to get a counter example. I found one with $n = 7$.

Comment: Maybe, you can tell me your counter example for $n=7$ ?

Comment: I'm not here to spoon feed you. You can some work to find if. If you're stuck, show what you've tried and where you're stuck.

Comment: Calvin is correct about the counter example. One thing you can do is fix $n-1$ numbers and see how you can achieve maximum (LHS-RHS) by adjusting the $n$th number.

Comment: If you don't show your work in the original question, people risk writing a detailed answer then see the post get deleted. Unfair to their efforts.

Comment: @CalvinLin There's also a counter example when $n=6$. If $n\le 5$ the inequality actually holds.

Comment: @NeatMath Yea, I'm aware of $n = 6$. I went one larger to make it easier to find. Are you able to prove it for $n \leq 5$? That's of interest to me, as it's less clear how to use $a_i \in [1,n]$.

Comment: @CalvinLin Yeah it's straightforward, pretty much along the line of your thinking.

Answer (score 1):

**Update** We can prove if $n\ge 6$, we always have $$ \frac{(n-1)\cdot 1+n}{n}>n^{\frac 2n}$$

For $n=6$ we have shown it at the end of the proof below. If it's true for $n$, the above inequality is equivalent to $$\left( 2 - \frac 1n\right)^n > n^2$$

Now,$$\left( 2 - \frac{1}{n+1} \right)^{n+1} - (n+1)^2 > \left( 2 - \frac{1}{n} \right)^{n+1} - (n+1)^2 \\> n^2 \left( 2-\frac 1n\right) -(n+1)^2 = n(n-3)-1 > 0$$

**Conclusion**: the inequality holds if and only if $n\le 5$.

---

If $n=1$ it's trivial. If $n\ge2$, consider the function $$f(x)=\frac{x+S}{n}-(xP)^{\frac{2}{n} }$$
where $S>0,P>0$.

$$f'(x)=\frac 1n - \frac 2n P^\frac 2n x^{\frac 2n-1} \implies f''(x)=\frac 2n \frac{n-2}{n}P^\frac 2n x^{\frac 2n -2}\ge 0$$

Therefore $f(x)$ obtains its maximum at either $x=1$ or $x=n$.

Hence we only need to show that

$$\frac{k\cdot n + (n-k) \cdot 1}{n} \le \left(n^k \cdot 1^{n-k}\right)^{\frac 2n}, \forall k \in \{0, 1, \ldots, n \} $$

For $n\le 5$ we can prove the above is true by manual calculation.

If $n=6$ there is a counter example: $a_1 = a_2 = \cdots = a_5=1, a_6=6$ (if $a_i=1$ is not allowed, just make it arbitrarily close to $1$): AM $\approx 1.83333$, but GM$^2 \approx 1.8171$.